# How to remove links from a PHP string using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm using a chat bot script, if a user name was `test@test.com` the bot will reply @ `<a href= mailto:test@test.com>test@test.com</a>` with a mailto link. I want the reply to be only `test@test.com` without the link, I tried `preg_replace` and `str_replace` but I don't really know the exact code to use, I've tried the following but didnt work !

```
$name = preg_replace('/<a href="([^<]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/', '', $name);
```

The whole code I'm using for replacements is this:

```
$name = str_replace (chr(0xc2).chr(0xa0), "_", $name);
$name = str_replace ("'", "", $name);
$name = str_replace ("&quot;", '"', $name);
$name = str_replace ("&amp;", "&", $name);
$name = str_replace ("&lt;", "", $name);
$name = str_replace ("&gt;", "", $name);
$name = str_replace ("&", "_", $name);
$name = str_replace ("*", "_", $name);
$name = preg_replace('/[^ \p{L}\p{N} \@ \_ \- \.\#\$\&\!]/u', '', $name);
$name = preg_replace('/<a href="([^<]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/', '', $name);
```

Comment: This blog post will help your case http://themessycode.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-parse-html-with-regex.html

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to replace it? Just use preg_match() with a regex similar to this:

`<a href=[^>]+>([^<]*)</a>`

so overall your code would look like this

```
<?php
$regex = '#<a href=[^>]+>([^<]*)</a>#';
$email = '<a href= mailto:test@test.com>test@test.com</a>';

preg_match($regex, $email, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
/*
output:
string(13) "test@test.com"
*/
?>
```

Comment: this is in case of email test@test.com, this is just to show that it's an email name, i want it to remove the mailto link from any name that matches name@email.com not only test@test.com

Comment: No, this doesn't only work on test@test.com, why would you think that? `$email` here is equivalent to `$name` in your question.

Comment: so if i want to use the code for any name that is in email format what should i use ?!

Comment: The code above. Sorry, but I don't really know what your question is. After `preg_match` `$matches[1]` contains your value. So you could do `$name = $matches[1]` for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above makes a lot of assumptions when doing the preg_replace so it's going to fail lots unfortunately :( Here's why...

- It assumes every link has the 'href' attribute directly after the 'a' tag. What if there's a different attribute in front of it?
- It assumes there are no other html tags inside the 'a' tag. If the link had the 'strong' tag inside it, the link would not be matched.
- I'm pretty sure too that if there's more than one link in the list it's going to remove everything between the first link and the second because it hasn't got anything to stop it being greedy.
- Finally, it's not been told to be insensitive. This means that if the link had A HREF in it, that wouldn't be found either.

I'm not saying my solution is 100% secure but I've tested it in scenarios I'm aware of and I think it's an upgrade from the answer above!...

```
$email = preg_replace("/<a.+?href.+?>.+?<\/a>/is","",$email);
```

The 'i' modifier makes it insensitive
The 's' modifier takes into account links that might be broken with newline breaks.

I'd always recommend populating a string with different  links in different formats, different orders etc. That's always the best way to test things work. Assuming eveyone types links as My test is going to get you into lots of sticky situations :)

Good luck!